# AdTapsy integration: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to integrate AdTapsy into my swift project but I get the following errors despite having added the libraries listed on their support page.

[image]

I have also added the following linker flags:

[image]

Comment: Have you added AdTapsy SDK to `build phases>Link Binary with libaries` ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that XCode funds AdTapsy, but cannot find 3rd party ad network libraries.
Check that the libraries exists in Project/AdTapsy/AdNetworks and in Build phases>Link Binary with libraries.

To include them again, delete the old folder, and drag and drop the AdTapsy folder to your project and select "Copy items into destination group's folder", this should fix the issue.